# How to uninstall ApacheDS installed in linux using .bin file

Tags: apache, apacheds

I have installed ApacheDS form this link
http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/download/download-linux-bin.html

It is installed in the opt folder.

How can I uninstall it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you must have root access then? The 32-bit .bin I've just downloaded attempted to install files to `/opt/apacheds-[$VERNUM]/, /etc/init.d/, and /var/lib/apacheds-[$VERNUM]`. Because all of those locations should be protected against user writes in all linux distributions by default that I'm aware of, I will assume you can escalate privileges as necessary to perform the following actions.

Another assumption I will go on is that you chose the default installation locations offered you when the .bin installer requested you provide configuration options for installation paths. When I ran it just now it asked me a question per path and I had only to press the "ENTER" key to continue using its defaults.

If you're uncertain about how to obtain root access try to prefix each command with `sudo`, and, failing that, try running the command `su` once alone before attempting to run any of the following.

```
### First verify install paths with root level find command
# find / -type d -name *apacheds* ; find /etc/init.d -name *apacheds*
### Review outputs of above commands and verify they match the following \
### globbing rm command before running it.
### CAUTION: If used incorrectly rm -rf could do some very annoying damage 
# rm -rf /{opt,var/lib,etc/init.d}/apacheds*
```

Comment: well I installed the 64 bit version with default configurations. I managed to delete the opt file by using rm /opt/apacheds-2.0.0-M15/ -R and removed the user that got created for login. I am not sure whether     it was entirely deleted.